# NetworkOnMainThreadException in Service

Tags: android, networkonmainthread

I'm getting a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` in my `Service` class, which by nature doesn't make sense, because Services are background processes as far as I understand.

In the Service method, I'm making a call to a static helper method to download data. I'm using the DefaultHttpClient as well.

What's going on here?

Comment: Can you show your code for easier investigation?

Comment: Check out my post about the **[`NetworkOnMainThreadException`](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html)**. It explains why this might occurs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`onStartCommand()` runs on the UI thread in a `Service`. Try using [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html), or alternatively use any other threading method in the `Service` (`Handler`/`Runnable`, `AsyncTask`).

Comment: It doesn't allowed to call AsyncTask in service, 'cause it should be executed from main tread, am I right ?

Comment: @bgplaya You can definitely use `AsyncTask` in a `Service`. As I said above, a regular `Service` runs on the main (UI) thread.

Comment: I should review my code, but seems like I had troubles using `AsyncTask` in `Service`: maybe I just called it not in `onStartCommand()`

Answer (score 0):

Service callbacks all run on the main thread, aka the UI thread. If you wish to do background work, either start a Thread, or use IntentService's onHandleIntent(Intent i).

Answer (score 0):

> The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a
>   networking operation on its main thread.
>
> This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or
>   higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do
>   networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily
>   discouraged.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

Answer (score 0):

i just resolve this problem by using this :

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    RefreshDBAsync task = new RefreshDBAsync(this);
    task.execute();

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

RefreshDBAsync is making request to a server at every 5 minutes